# Binomial Distribution with Die

Tags: probability

A die is rolled eight times. What is the chance that in the first five rolls, two sixes showed up given that in eight rolls three sixes showed up?

I think that this requires me to use the binomial distribution, but I am not sure how to use it to solve this problem. Also, I know that the answer is $\frac{30}{56}$, but I'm looking to learn how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, binomial distribution with conditioning.

Let $X$ be the count of sixes in the first five rolls, and $Y$ the count in the next three.   These will be independent (no common die) and their sum will be the count of sixes in all eight rolls.   Thus: $$X\perp Y\\X\sim\mathcal{Bin}(5, \tfrac 16) \\ Y\sim\mathcal{Bin}(3, \tfrac 16)\\ X+Y\sim\mathcal{Bin}(8, \tfrac 16) $$

You are after $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X=2\mid X+Y=3) = \dfrac{\mathsf P(X=2)~\mathsf P(Y=1)}{\mathsf P(X+Y=3)}\end{align}$$

So, do you know the probability mass functions for the Binomial distribution?    Incidentally, there will be significant cancelations.

The end result should be (no peeking until you've tried):

> $$\mathsf P(X=2\mid X+Y=3) ~=~ \dfrac{\binom 52 \binom 31}{\binom 83}$$

Can you see another way to arrive at this result?   It should look familiar.

Answer (score 2):

We are given that $3$ sixes showed up in $8$ rolls. The number of ways in which this could have happened is the number of ways to arrange the $3$ sixes among the $8$ rolls, which is $\binom{8}{3}= \frac{8 \times 7 \times 6}{3 \times 2 \times 1} = 56$.

Now, suppose that in the first five rolls, $2$ sixes came. The number of ways of arranging these $2$ sixes among the $5$ rolls is $\binom{5}{2} = 10$. Furthermore, we also have to look at the one remaining six. This can come either in the sixth,seventh or eighth roll, hence there are three ways to arrange this six. Multiplying, we get $30$ possibilities of $2$ sixes coming in the first five rolls.

Hence, the answer is $\frac{30}{56}$.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume you want exactly $2$ sixes and not at least $2$ sixes.

$X_n$ is the number of $6's$ in $n$ rolls.

$P(X_5 = 2)  = {5 \choose 2} (\frac 16)^2 (\frac 56)^3$

$P(X_8 = 3)  = {8\choose 3} (\frac 16)^3 (\frac 56)^5$

Bayes law

$P(A|B) = \frac {P(B|A) P(A)}{P(B)}$

$P(X_5 = 2|X_8 = 3) = \frac {P(X_8 = 3|X_5 = 2) P(X_5 = 2)}{P(X_8 = 3)}$

we are missing one component:

$P(X_8 = 3|X_5 = 2)$

What is the chance of rolling three $6's$ in $8$ rolls given that there were $2$ sixes in the first $5?$ 
It is the same as rolling one $6$ in $3$ rolls.

given the above, can you find $P(X_3 = 1)$ and put it all togheter?